# NHibernate 2nd level cache and web farms

Tags: nhibernate

A excerpt from http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate

"The life time of the second level cache is tied to the session factory and not to an individual session. Once an entity is loaded by its unique id and the second level cache is active the entity is available for all other sessions (of the same session factory)"

If the above is true and you have a web farm I *think* the following is true

1) there will be a SessionFactory per application (each web server in my case)
2) there will be a distinct 2nd level cache for each web server
3) data loaded in to the 2nd level cache for server A cannot be utilised by server B

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in article you mentioned [First and Second Level caching in NHibernate](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate):

> NHibernate is design as an enterprise OR/M product, and as such, it
>   has very good support for running in web farms scenarios. This support
>   include running along side with distributed caches, including
>   immediate farm wide updates.  NHibernate goes to great lengths to
>   ensure cache consistency in these scenarios...

If distributed cache is used, immediate updates are raised around all servers (e.g. to drop off stale data)

see also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587493/1679310

Comment: ok so when it says "life time of the second level cache is tied to the session factory" it's a bit misleading IMO. Should it say something more like: When a SessionFactory attempts to create a 2ndLC it first checks to see if one already exists, if one does it uses it, if one does not it will create one. All subsequent SessionFactorys will make use of the same pre-existing 2ndLC. What is still not clear is when the 2ndLC expires? If all servers are shut down and restarted will they pick up the 2ndLC that was there from before?

Comment: I think I do have your point. That statement means, that 2nd cache is not for a session but for a complete factory. But if the distributed cache approach is used, the update (to clear caches) can be sent to all servers